# html table issue when zooming into web browser

Tags: html

so Im going to rephrase my question. Basically whenever I zoom into the web browser my table starts to either move down or the text on one table gets pushed ontop of the other table so they overlap. How can I have it so that the positioning of each text/images etc. all stay in the same position as I zoom into the web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate your question by giving a link to the page.

As much I can get from here is that you can use liquid dimensions that is defining width and height in percent in css.

Comment: i didnt publish anything yet, sorry...and what do u mean by liquid dimensions ?

Comment: so far my table looks like this <table  border="0"  align = "left" >

Comment: the second table looks like this <table align = "right"  border="0"  >...so they are two tables next to each other

Comment: It is that instead of defining the width and height in pixels, you can  use percent. Like <table width="100%">. Can you post the code for your page.

Comment: Ok. Try changing it to <table width="100%" align="left" border="0">

Comment: i did that and it made the table on the right gets pushed down making the left table taking all the space on the top from left to right and i will try to post it

Comment: cant post my code :( since IM a new user..is there anyway i can send it to u?

Answer (score 0):

Give percentage width. may be it's works

Comment: i tried percentage, doesnt work, it still has that same problem by pushing the right table all the way down

Comment: basically i want the width to be fixed so when i make the broswer smaller or larger it stays the look stays the same, like the table on the right stays in its position

Comment: would you please send me the link that you have done, so that i can able to justify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code like this:
< table width="50%" align="left" border="0" >  < table width="50%" align="right" border="0">

Comment: u know maybe its because when i test my code im testing it in 83 percent zoom not 100 percent because the more u increase the wrose it looks, when u decrease the zoom then its all good cuz it still looks the same

Comment: i can either change it up a little bt but one thing i noticed is that my browser isnt showing a horizantal scroll bar when i zoom hence all the content is getting all over each other, is there a way where i cna have a horizantal bar appear when i zoom in?